# Image of Abel-Jacobi map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ with $h^{2,1}(X)=0$.

Is the image of the Abel-Jacobi map $$\mathcal{Z}^2(X)_{\text{hom}} \rightarrow J^3(X)$$
torsion?

Comment: Is there any example of threefold that $H^{2,1}(X)=0$, while $H^{3,0}(X)\neq 0$?

Comment: @YilongZhang Actually, I don't know. I am equally interested in analogs of this question for $J^{2k-1}(X)$, when $h^{k,k-1}=0$.

Comment: @YilongZhang Examples: rigid Calabi-Yau threefolds.

Comment: Yes, I do find such an example on some notes. I think your question is related to Griffiths groups. However, the classical works in this area that I know (by Clemens, Voisin, etc) need deformation theory, but a Calabi-Yau with $H^{2,1}=0$ cannot be deformed. I don't know if there are other ways to think about this question.